# Mysql query involving 2 tables with a timestamp column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, nested

I'm trying to write some software for MTT (Manufacturing To Target).  One table holds information about the target, and another table is for tracking datapoints.

In it's simplest form, the tables are laid out as follows:

```
Table target
    field pk_target int pk autoincrement
    field timestamp double
    field target double
    field UCL double //upper control limit
    field LCL double //lower control limit

Table dataPoint
    field pk_dataPoint int pk autoincrement
    field timestamp as double
    field value as double
```

The target table will be updated only as needed, which could be anywhere from once per month to once per day or more.  The dataPoint table will be updated once every 4 hours.
I would like to make a query that combines data from both tables, so that every entry from the dataPoint table is listed along with the most recent data from the target table for the particular timestamp in the dataPoint table.

For example, lets say that the the target table contains 2 entries:
pk_target=1,timestamp=1000,target=11,UCL=13,LCL=9
pk_target=2,timestamp=1200,target=10,UCL=12,LCL=8

And lets assume that the dataPoints table contains 3 entries:

```
pk_dataPoint=1,timestamp=1001,value=9.4
pk_dataPoint=2,timestamp=1125,value=9.7
pk_datapoint=3,timestamp=1420,value=10.1
```

So the query I'm having building should return a resultset like:

```
dataPoint.pk_DataPoint=1,dataPoint.timestamp=1001.dataPoint.value=9.4,target.target=11
dataPoint.pk_DataPoint=2,dataPoint.timestamp=1125.dataPoint.value=9.7,target.target=11
dataPoint.pk_DataPoint=3,dataPoint.timestamp=1420.dataPoint.value=10.1,target.target=10
```

Notice that in the example dataset above, the target.target is 11 for the first 2 entries, as the timestamp for the target was the lartest in the target table that was still less than the timestamp entry in the dataPoint table.  Essentially saying that "for this datapoint, the target should have been 'X' as determined by the timestamps".

Can anyone give me some input on how I would accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select dp.*,
       (select target
        from Target t
        where t.timestamp <= dp.timestamp
        order by t.timestamp desc
        limit 1
       ) as target
from DataPoint dp;
```

This is assuming that the most appropriate data is the most recent from `Target` *before* the timestamp in `DataPoint`.

Comment: Short oversight..  What if I want to return multiple fields from the target table (to include UCL and LCL for example)?

Comment: @user2787435 . . . You can return the `id` and then join back to the original table.